# when retrieve data through ajax which contains html tags are retrieve as string and not display in html as tags

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

i am retrieving data through ajax which consist of list tags(li) but when through ajax html function i display it in 
ul it not take it as li but display as string
my ajax code is

```
<?php

include 'classes/connection_and_crud.php';

$query = "select *from admin_notifications where status=1 AND receiveFrom='doctors'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$num = mysql_num_rows($result) ;
////
$query1 = "select *from admin_notifications where receiveFrom='doctors'";

$result1 = mysql_query($query1);
?>
<li>
    <p>You have <?php echo $num; ?> Messages</p>
</li>
```

Comment: Lets see your jquery, also suggestion, [**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1):

Pass the data through html_entity_decode() function.

https://www.php.net/html_entity_decode